# A basic question on linear maps and restriction to invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a linear map $T:V \to V$. Choose one non-zero element (suppose it exists) and take its span. Suppose this subspace is invariant under $T$. Does that imply that any complement of this one-dimensional subspace will also be invariant under $T$. I don't think so.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258502/do-t-invariant-subspaces-necessarily-have-a-t-invariant-complement

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan : But suppose I consider the quotient space with respect to that one-dimensional space. Let $v,w \in V$ belongs to the same element in the quotient space then $T(v),T(w)$ also belongs to the same element in the quotient space. So, we get some kind of invariance. Is not this contradictory (because quotient space is isomorphic to complement) ? Am I making sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take
$$
T=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right),
$$
the vector $\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
    0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ and a complement Span$\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    0 \\
    1 \\
  \end{array}
\right).$